# How to display or fetch product form data in WooCommerce REST API

Tags: javascript, html, json, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to create a furniture pack based on a form the person answers a form: type of accommodation monthly budget and commitment date
depending on the type of accommodation, there are compulsory categories:
e.g. for a studio, the pack must include a bed, dressing room, table and chair.
Property prices depend on the budget indicated.

But unfortunately, I can't retrieve the products to display in a sun widget via JavaScript.

here are the steps:

- Step 1 - Retrieve form data
  Create an HTML/CSS form to enter information (type of accommodation, duration, budget)
  Add a listener to the form submit
  In the callback, retrieve values using JavaScript
- Step 2 - Validate data
  Check that values are numeric and consistent
  If error, display message
  Otherwise, store validated values in JavaScript variables
- Step 3 - Define categories
  Create a JavaScript object that associates the housing type with the required categories
  According to the type retrieved, retrieve the right categories
- Step 4 - Calculate budgets
  Calculate total budget and margin with JavaScript formula
  Store budgets in variables
- Step 5 - Allocate budget
  Retrieve WooCommerce products with REST API
  For each category, allocate budget pro rata with JavaScript
  Store allocated budgets in a JavaScript object
- Step 6 - Suggest initial package
  Browse categories and allocated budgets
  For each category, select the least expensive product
  Add product to a JavaScript table

But here I've got an error when I try to fetch product via REST API.

```
{
"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
"message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
```

```
<div id="products"></div>
<div id="error" class="error-message" style="display: none;">Erreur lors de la récupération des produits WooCommerce.</div>

<script>
    // Récupérer consumer key et secret 
    const key = 'ck_d35ea04d913695e0ec70c519fffc82aab72f1d7c';
    const secret = 'cs_fdb72145eaf63c5c711918fdbd61ebb4e40cc4ec';

    // Récupérer le token d'auth
    fetch('/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            consumer_key: key,
            consumer_secret: secret,
        })
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Erreur lors de la récupération du token d\'authentification.');
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const token = data.token;

        // Récupérer les produits
        return fetch('/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=5', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
        });
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Erreur lors de la récupération des produits WooCommerce.');
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        // Parcourir les produits
        data.forEach(product => {
            // Récupérer les infos 
            const id = product.id;
            const title = product.name;
            const imageSrc = product.images[0].src;
            const price = product.price;

            // Générer le HTML
            const html = `
                <div class="product">
                    <h3>${title}</h3>
                    <img src="${imageSrc}" />
                    <div>${price} €</div>
                </div>
            `;

            // Insérer dans la page
            document.querySelector('#products').innerHTML += html;
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error:', err);
        document.querySelector('#error').style.display = 'block';
    });
</script>
```

I try to fetch the product via postman in OAuth 1.0 I can fetch them but not on the website.

I can do it via PHP, but I want to be able to flexibly put the different widgets, and it will be easier form me to connect the different pages.
I try to apply the different method like force SSL certificate but nothing I don't know where is the problem.